# Duplicate values wtih column changing based on select from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, sql-insert

I am trying to duplicate rows table1, for each response of a select from table2, with changing the value of one of the columns to the results from table2

So here is my select from table1 to ge tthe values I want to duplicate:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM table1 WHERE CODE = 'abcd'
```

response:

```
Code     zone
abcd      1
abcd      2
abcd      3
abcd      4
```

And I want all the results from the above select to be duplicated for each of the responses from the below select

```
SELECT DISTINCT CODE AS code
FROM table2
WHERE CODE LIKE '%abcd%'
```

Goal:

```
Code     zone
abcde      1
abcde      2
abcde      3
abcde      4
abcdef     1
abcdef     2
abcdef     3
abcdef     4
zabcd      1
zabcd      2
zabcd      3
zabcd      4
```

I then want to add these values to table1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you want a `CROSS JOIN`:

```
SELECT B.code, A.zone
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Code, zone 
      FROM table1 
      WHERE CODE = 'abcd') A
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT CODE AS code
            FROM table2
            WHERE CODE LIKE '%abcd%') B
;
```

If you want to insert this data in `table1`:

```
INSERT INTO table1(code, zone)
SELECT B.code, A.zone
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Code, zone 
      FROM table1 
      WHERE CODE = 'abcd') A
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT CODE AS code
            FROM table2
            WHERE CODE LIKE '%abcd%') B
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM table1
                 WHERE code = B.code
                 AND zone = A.zone)
;
```

Comment: Is this inserting these rows into table1?

Comment: @Mennyg nope, it isn't

Comment: So thats my question. I need to add the results of this query (which works btw) to table1

Comment: well, that wasn't actually in the question